# Retrieving CreatedById of a custom metadata type

Tags: custom-metadata, audit-fields

Is it possible to query fields like `CreatedById` on a custom metadata type record? Evidently not, but apparently I should be able to?!

```
SELECT CreatedById from MyObject__mdt   

No such column 'CreatedById' on entity 'MyObject__mdt'
```

We can see the field on the object and strangely it can even be referenced in a validation rule.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CreatedById is not available in soap api of custom metadata. Check here:- [Custom Metadata Type__mdt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_custommetadatatype__mdt.htm)

Available fields are:-

1. Custom Field__c
2. DeveloperName
3. isProtected
4. Label
5. Language
6. MasterLabel
7. NamespacePrefix
8. QualifiedApiName

As a workaround, You can create a field with default value as current user id.

[image]